# Changing 200 Columns from varchar to float

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is there an easy script I can write (without naming all the columns), to change 200+ columns from varchar(50) to float? The data technically is a float but was accidentally created in varchar. I don't care about the precision that I would lose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately the change will name the columns in an `ALTER TABLE` statement.  With a little cleverness and patience, though, you can generate that statement by string-slinging sys.syscolumns.  Roughly something like

```
select 'alter table tablename '
select 'alter column [' + name + '] float not NULL' 
from sys.syscolumns where id = objectid(tablename) order by name
```

That will produce SQL to do what you want.  Inspect carefully, then execute.

Comment: Inspect very carefully.  You probably won't be able to alter the primary key column.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an update for query written by James K. Lowden above that gives you only columns that are type varchar(50). Hopefully this will make things a bit easier but you’d still need to examine all queries very carefully.

```
select 'ALTER TABLE ' + s.name + '.' + T.name + '      ALTER COLUMN [' + C.name + '] float not null'  
from sys.columns C
inner join sys.tables T on C.object_id = T.object_id
inner join sys.schemas S on T.schema_id = S.schema_id
where 
C.system_type_id = 167 -- this is type for varchar
and C.max_length = 50 -- selects only varchars(50) and avoids others
```